# Should race conditions be handled in form or view?

Tags: python, django, database

Lets suppose I have to withdraw money from a specific wallet object.

So I first check if x amount of money is in wallet..

Then I lock wallet object in form clean() method, then check it. If the wallet has enough money, form is valid and we proceed to the view.

In the view the withdraw action happens but in the view, the wallet object won't be locked anymore.. If two threads manage to reach to the view at the same time, race condition may occur.

should the transfer action happen in the clean() form method where the wallet object will be locked or validate the amount of money of the wallet in the view?